# Reversing a sentence using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to reverse a sentence using recursion and print it out backwards. Right now after it prompts me to type in a sentence, it does not allow me to enter any input and ends. Is there something wrong with sc.nextLine()? How do I input a sentence as a string.

```
private static void testNum3() 
    {
        System.out.print("Type in a sentence:");
        String sentence= sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(reverse(sentence));

    }

    public static String reverse (String sentence)
    {
        if (sentence.length()== 0) 
            return sentence;

        return reverse(sentence.substring(1)) + sentence.charAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling any Scanner methods elsewhere in your program?

Comment: I use sc.next() elsewhere. Do they all have to be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use sc.next() elsewhere. Do they all have to be the same?

No, but you have to take care to handle the EOL or "End-Of-Line" token properly. If you call `sc.next()` and leave a dangling EOL token, it will be "swallowed" next time you call `sc.nextLine()` preventing you from getting input.

One solution: call `sc.nextLine()` when you need to handle the EOL token.

For instance, if you're getting an int from the user and its the only thing entered on the line, sometimes you must do:

```
int myVar = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  // swallow dangling EOL token with this call

// now you can safely call this below
String myString = sc.nextLine();
```